# Center nth-child elements on different display widths

Tags: html, css

How can i center nth-child elements here ? Right now it do the trick and shows my divs in line what is just what i wanted, but how can i center the elements in middle of my page , depending on browser width ? Right now if i center elements by changing left: px; it work on only on my main display, but when site is visited from browsers with different display size it is not centered.  How to fix this problem? 
Or maybe i can do something else here ?

```css
/* Overwiev bottom */ 



 .content-box-s {
    margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
    width: 222px;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: -75px;
 position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.95s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.95s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.95s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.95s ease-in-out;

}
.content-box-s:hover {
    margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
    width: 222px;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;

 
}
.content-box-s:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  
}

.content-box-s:nth-child(2) {
  left: 222px;

}

.content-box-s:nth-child(3) {
  left: 442px;

}

.content-box-s .header {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/b9de2f5b06c823d628d22c4067ee35.gif") no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.content-box-s .content {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/bd764e9b39a1a48ad708039fda1bde.gif") repeat-y;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.content-box-s p {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
.content-box-s .footer {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/174d5c09f617701fcaf1664a414869.gif") no-repeat;
    height: 21px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
div.content-box-s .header h3 {
    color: #6f9fc8;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 222px;
    text-align: center;
}
.contentbox {
    margin: 0 3px 0 2px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left, #buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right, #buttonz .contentbox .header, #buttonz .contentbox .footer, #buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left, #buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right, .contentbox .header .c-left, .contentbox .header .c-right, .contentbox .header, .contentbox .footer, .contentbox .footer .c-left, .contentbox .footer .c-right {
    background-image: url("../images/Build_tmp/191d6af9367f608bbee2743866c489.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 -1px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .header, .contentbox .header {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left, #buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right, .contentbox .header .c-left, .contentbox .header .c-right {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 35px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left, .contentbox .header .c-left {
    background-position: 0 -33px;
    left: -2px;
    right: auto;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right, .contentbox .header .c-right {
    background-position: 100% -66px;
    left: auto;
    right: -2px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .content, .contentbox .content {
    border-left: 5px double #000;
    border-right: 5px double #000;
    background: #0d1014;
    margin: 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .footer, .contentbox .footer {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
    height: 21px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 7px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left, #buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right, .contentbox .footer .c-left, .contentbox .footer .c-right {
    height: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 35px;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left, .contentbox .footer .c-left {
    background-position: 0 -125px;
    left: -8px;
    right: auto;
}
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right, .contentbox .footer .c-right {
    background-position: 100% -150px;
    left: auto;
    right: -8px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-faster-img {
    background-position: -25px -75px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster:hover .build-finish-img {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-finish-img {
    background-position: 0 -75px;
}  
#inhalt .content-box-s .content {
    min-height: 46px;
    height: auto!important;
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 177px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:link, #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:visited, #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:active {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.no-touch #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction.active {
    background: #171d23;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #171d23), color-stop(100%, #101419));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#171d23', endColorstr='#101419', GradientType=0);
    border: 1px solid #171d23;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.queue {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .transport_ecke {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ae6b67d617f5b4a9ad508219ca02b8.png");
    margin: 0 0 -18px 0;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    top: -16px;
    width: 35px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    width: 162px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster-img, #inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/f67f646a967bc6e4f54dcfcc2c3f2b.png") -25px 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 1px 7px 0 7px;
    width: 25px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .order_dm {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-faster-img {
    background-position: -25px -50px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-finish-img {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost, #inhalt .content-box-s .buy_dm {
    color: #848484;
    display: inline-block;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost .oldPrice {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-style: italic;
}
img.queuePic {
    border: 1px solid #141e26;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
a:hover img.queuePic {
    border-color: #e7ae46;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 43px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first div {
    position: relative;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .desc {
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 130px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timer {
    color: #fff;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .ausbau {
    padding-top: 8px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .level {
    color: #a26d00;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll {
    padding: 5px 0 0 12px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll .shipAllCountdown, #inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip .shipCountdown {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction tr.queue td {
    color: #848484;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
}
#inhalt .content-box-s .queue_link {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 32px;
}
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:link, #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:visited, .no-touch #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:hover, #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:active {
    background: transparent none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
}
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher {
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity: .6;
    -khtml-opacity: .6;
    opacity: .6;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%}
 table.construction #Countdown, table.construction #researchCountdown, table.construction .shipCountdown {
    font-weight: 700;
}
#stationbuilding .construction a, #stationbuilding .construction a:active {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/0349d693b02c1927643248e4167cf8.gif") no-repeat;
    color: #ff9600;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}
.no-touch #stationbuilding .construction a:hover, #stationbuilding .construction a.active {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}
.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li a:hover, .no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a:hover, #resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active, #resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link, #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active, .no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover, .no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover, #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ce2e012805bae16d3bc0967600eb58.gif") no-repeat;
    color: #ff9600;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover, .no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover {
    background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}
.dark_highlight {
    background: #181e25 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1030px repeat-x;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2d3743), color-stop(100%, #181e25));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: #28323e #222b34 #232a34 #222b34;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 0;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.dark_highlight:hover {
    background: #2d3743 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1080px repeat-x;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #181e25), color-stop(100%, #2d3743));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: #232b34 #232b34 #29323d #232b34;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
}

#planet1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 679px;
    
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info{
 color:#fff;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 position:absolute;
 line-height:18px; 
 padding:5px 8px;
}
#planet1 .palnet_block_info span{
 color:#27db7d;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info2{
 color:#fff;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
 position:absolute;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:18px; 
 padding:20px 10px;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;
}

.planet2 {
    display: inline-block;
 text-align:center;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.planet2 .img_img{
    width: 220px;
 text-align:center;
    height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
 
}


.planet2:hover {
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
   
}


.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="inhalt">
 <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header"><h3>Buildings</h3></div>
       <div class="content">  
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
           <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="idle">
           <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no buildings done at the moment. Click here to get to your buildings page." href="../game/game.php?page=buildings">
    You are not building anything at the moment.
   </a> 
    </td>
                </tr>   
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>



<div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header"><h3>Research</h3></div>
       <div class="content">    
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
           <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="idle">
           <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no research done at the moment. Click here to get to your research lab." href="../game/game.php?page=research">
          You are not researching anything at the moment.
   </a> 
    </td>
                </tr>   
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>



<div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header"><h3>Hangar</h3></div>
       <div class="content">    
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
           <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="idle">
           <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There are not any activity in hangar at the moment. Click here to get to your hangar. " href="../game/game.php?page=shipyard&mode=fleet">
          There are not any activity in hangar at the moment.
   </a> 
    </td>
                </tr>   
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
 </div>   

</div>
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using flexbox to achieve this. Apply `position: fixed;` to just your `#inhalt` container and child elements can then be positioned dynamically using flexbox. You can use `position: relative;` with some positioning for your hover effects.

Working Example:

```css
/* Overwiev bottom */

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#inhalt {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-box-s {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  width: 222px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -75px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.95s ease-in-out;
}

.content-box-s:hover {
  margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
  width: 222px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.content-box-s .header {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/b9de2f5b06c823d628d22c4067ee35.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.content-box-s .content {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/bd764e9b39a1a48ad708039fda1bde.gif") repeat-y;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.content-box-s p {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.content-box-s .footer {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/174d5c09f617701fcaf1664a414869.gif") no-repeat;
  height: 21px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

div.content-box-s .header h3 {
  color: #6f9fc8;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 222px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contentbox {
  margin: 0 3px 0 2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
#buttonz .contentbox .header,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header,
.contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-image: url("../images/Build_tmp/191d6af9367f608bbee2743866c489.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header,
.contentbox .header {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-left,
.contentbox .header .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -33px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .header .c-right,
.contentbox .header .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -66px;
  left: auto;
  right: -2px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .content,
.contentbox .content {
  border-left: 5px double #000;
  border-right: 5px double #000;
  background: #0d1014;
  margin: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer,
.contentbox .footer {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
  height: 21px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 7px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-left,
.contentbox .footer .c-left {
  background-position: 0 -125px;
  left: -8px;
  right: auto;
}

#buttonz .contentbox .footer .c-right,
.contentbox .footer .c-right {
  background-position: 100% -150px;
  left: auto;
  right: -8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled:hover .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -75px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content {
  min-height: 46px;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 46px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 177px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:link,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:visited,
#inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:active {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #inhalt .content-box-s .content td.idle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction.active {
  background: #171d23;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #171d23), color-stop(100%, #101419));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #171d23 0, #101419 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#171d23', endColorstr='#101419', GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid #171d23;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.queue {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .transport_ecke {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ae6b67d617f5b4a9ad508219ca02b8.png");
  margin: 0 0 -18px 0;
  padding: 1px 5px 2px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  top: -16px;
  width: 35px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 162px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster-img,
#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/f67f646a967bc6e4f54dcfcc2c3f2b.png") -25px 0 no-repeat;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 1px 7px 0 7px;
  width: 25px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .order_dm {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-faster-img {
  background-position: -25px -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .build-faster.disabled .build-finish-img {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost,
#inhalt .content-box-s .buy_dm {
  color: #848484;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .dm_cost .oldPrice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.queuePic {
  border: 1px solid #141e26;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a:hover img.queuePic {
  border-color: #e7ae46;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 43px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .first div {
  position: relative;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .desc {
  padding-left: 12px;
  width: 130px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timer {
  color: #fff;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .ausbau {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .level {
  color: #a26d00;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll {
  padding: 5px 0 0 12px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdAll .shipAllCountdown,
#inhalt .content-box-s .construction .data .timeProdShip .shipCountdown {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .content table.construction tr.queue td {
  color: #848484;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

#inhalt .content-box-s .queue_link {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 32px;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:link,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:visited,
.no-touch #box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:hover,
#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher a.timeLink:active {
  background: transparent none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
}

#box #inhalt .buildingimg .construction .pusher {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity: .6;
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%
}

table.construction #Countdown,
table.construction #researchCountdown,
table.construction .shipCountdown {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#stationbuilding .construction a,
#stationbuilding .construction a:active {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/0349d693b02c1927643248e4167cf8.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.no-touch #stationbuilding .construction a:hover,
#stationbuilding .construction a.active {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a:hover,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
#resources #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active,
.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
#resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li a.active:link {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/ce2e012805bae16d3bc0967600eb58.gif") no-repeat;
  color: #ff9600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.no-touch #resources #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover,
.no-touch #resources-moon #buttonz ul#building li div.construction a:hover {
  background: url("../images/Build_tmp/9c93d3dba7052ea7fd1758007e7959.gif") no-repeat;
}

.dark_highlight {
  background: #181e25 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1030px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2d3743), color-stop(100%, #181e25));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d3743 0, #181e25 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #28323e #222b34 #232a34 #222b34;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 22%, 32%);
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.dark_highlight:hover {
  background: #2d3743 url("../images/Build_tmp/5fbbb1876fcff20a8a265c06862495.png") 0 -1080px repeat-x;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #181e25), color-stop(100%, #2d3743));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #181e25 0, #2d3743 100%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: #232b34 #232b34 #29323d #232b34;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 black, inset 0 -1px 1px 0 hsl(213, 27%, 26%);
}

#planet1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 679px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info span {
  color: #27db7d;
}

#planet1 .palnet_block_info2 {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.planet2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.planet2 .img_img {
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
}

.planet2:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 99, 71, 0.5);
}

.planet2 .img_description {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="inhalt">
  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Buildings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="idle">
              <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no buildings done at the moment. Click here to get to your buildings page." href="../game/game.php?page=buildings">
    You are not building anything at the moment.
   </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Research</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="idle">
              <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There is no research done at the moment. Click here to get to your research lab." href="../game/game.php?page=research">
          You are not researching anything at the moment.
   </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>



  <div class="content-box-s">
    <div class="header">
      <h3>Hangar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="construction active">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="idle">
              <a class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="There are not any activity in hangar at the moment. Click here to get to your hangar. " href="../game/game.php?page=shipyard&mode=fleet">
          There are not any activity in hangar at the moment.
   </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html or css is too long to inspect.

1. Remove `position:fixed` from all `.content-box-s`.
2. Verify that whole layout should move by moving `#inhalt`container. Which means all childs should be positioned based on `#inhalt` and should not use any hard-coded pixel values.
3. `fix` the position of `#inhalt` container only.
4. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer to position `#inhalt` horizontally center using flexbox.